# i3 - bindcode 229 and 230 not working

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, i3

I am trying to enable my keyboard LED's on Arch Linux and [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_backlight) I found this nice script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

from sys import argv
import dbus


def kb_light_set(delta):
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    kbd_backlight_proxy = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.UPower', '/org/freedesktop/UPower/KbdBacklight')
    kbd_backlight = dbus.Interface(kbd_backlight_proxy, 'org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight')

    current = kbd_backlight.GetBrightness()
    maximum = kbd_backlight.GetMaxBrightness()
    new = max(0, current + delta)

    if new >= 0 and new <= maximum:
        current = new
        kbd_backlight.SetBrightness(current)

    # Return current backlight level percentage
    return 100 * current / maximum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(argv[1:]) == 1:
        if argv[1] == "--up" or argv[1] == "+":
            # ./kb-light.py (+|--up) to increment
            print(kb_light_set(1))
        elif argv[1] == "--down" or argv[1] == "-":
            # ./kb-light.py (-|--down) to decrement
            print(kb_light_set(-1))
        else:
            print("Unknown argument:", argv[1])
    else:
        print("Script takes exactly one argument.", len(argv[1:]), "arguments provided.")
```

which works if I put it in `~/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/keyboard_backlights/`, make it executable and start it with one of the commands below:

```
~/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/keyboard_backlights/kb-light.py +
~/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/keyboard_backlights/kb-light.py -
```

Problem occurs when I try to implement this inside my i3 configuration file `~/.config/i3/config` like this ([user manual](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html)):

```
bindcode 229 exec "~/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/keyboard_backlights/kb-light.py -"
bindcode 230 exec "~/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/keyboard_backlights/kb-light.py +"
```

I can confirm `bindcode 229` and `bindcode 230` numbers if I exit my i3 window manager, use command `showkey` and then press the keys that I want to bind commands to. These two keys haven't been used anywhere else but this fails to work.

Comment: The keycodes and scancodes shown by `showkey` are only for the text console. They do not necessarily match the keycodes used in X11 (i.e. the GUI). To get the correct codes for use with `i3`, you can use the tool `xev` (from within a terminal emulator in an active X11 session, e.g. with `i3` running). Used as `xev -event keyboard` it will show only keyboard events. Case in point: the correct X11 keycodes for brightness control seem to be 232 and 233.

Comment: I found out about `xev` later. And you are correct - I used wrong keycodes, because I looked in console. I read somewhere that I have to move to console in order for `showkey` to work. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this answer was like this:

```
bindsym XF86KbdBrightnessDown exec --no-startup-id ~/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/keyboard_backlights/kb-light.py -
bindsym XF86KbdBrightnessUp exec --no-startup-id ~/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/keyboard_backlights/kb-light.py +
```